# Restrict Kendo Grid inline numeric text box editor to positive numbers only

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a Kendo Grid with inline editing enabled and a numeric text box in it to edit numeric values:

```
$("#g_Points").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: viewModel.myList,
    columns: [
        { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 250, editor: function (element, options) { element.text(options.model.Name) } },
        { field: "Available", title: "Points", width: 90, editable: true }
    ],
    editable: true,
    save: function (arg) {  
        arg.model.Available = arg.values.Available;
        saveRow(arg.model);
        this.cancelChanges();
    },
    scrollable: true
});
```

It works fine but I need to restrict the "Available" field to positive numbers only.

I tried this:

```
...
{ field: "Available", title: "Points", width: 90, editable: true, editor: myEditorFunction }
...

function myEditorFunction (container, options) {
    $('<input/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            min: 0
        });
}
```

And it restricts to only positive numbers only, but then the save functionality isn't working anymore. I can edit the values but when I leave the cell editing, the value returns to the default one.

How can I restrict my inline numeric textbox to positive numbers only?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work, here's what I did:

```
$("#g_Points").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: viewModel.myList,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Available: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 0 } }
                }
            }
        }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to set the name attribute of the input to be that of the field.

```
function myEditorFunction (container, options) {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '" />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            min: 0
        });
}
```

See [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor) for more info.